# We have the recurrence relation $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n = 4a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$. Could you find an odd integer factor of $a_{2015}$?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Question :

We have the recurrence relation $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$ and $a_n = 4a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$. Could you find an odd integer factor of $a_{2015}$?

I tried to find an explicit formula for this relationship, but it does not help us at all because we have roots in the explicit form.

Does someone could post a answer to this question or a partial answer that I can complete?

Comment: Some people take Putnam later, for various reasons. Please remove your question.

Comment: Not true! Exam provides for deferrals on individual basis for religious reasons.

Comment: Locking this for 1 day. @-ping me or flag for moderator attention, if something else is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit form is useful here. Find the explicit formula, figure out which of the root terms cancel and which terms are left. After that you can use binomial theorem to get it in terms of a sum, then prove that for any $a_m, a_m|a_{km}$ and then you can see that since the factors of $2015$ are $5$,$13$, and $31$, that $a_5|a_{2015}$ and that since $a_5 = 181*2$ that $181$ divides $a_{2015}$ and $181$ divides it too and is a prime.

Comment: Are you able to give me the explicit formula? I have already computed it during the exam, but I don't remember due the complexity of the expression. I already know it involves the following numbers: $\phi_1=2-\sqrt{3}$ and $\phi_2=2+\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @J.G It was $\frac{1}{2}(\phi_1+\phi_2)$.

Comment: @Panphobia How did you notice that $a_m|a_{km}$? I took your approach initially but that was not obvious to me!

Comment: @Panphobia Do you use a generating function to obtain this result?

Comment: If my memory does serve, I got that it was something like $$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} 2^{n-2k}3^k {n \choose n-2k}$$. From here you could check divisibility multiple ways, induction is one way to do it.

Comment: @Casteels I just wrote out like 25-30 terms and try to see some resemblance of a pattern. I did the same thing with B2, just wrote out 20 terms and figured out a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3& 4&5&6&7&8&9&10&\cdots\\
\hline
a_n\pmod{181} & 1 & 2 & 7 &26&97&0&-97&-26&-7&-2&-1&\cdots\\
\end{array}
$$